# Reformatting comments in WebStorm, specifically justification

Tags: javascript, comments, webstorm, reformatting

Is there anyway to configure the editor in WebStorm or any of the IntelliJ products so that there is a mouse or key sequence to justify block comments `/* */`, or even contiguous `//` comments? To do this adding ' `*` ' or ' `//` ' appropriately, or removing them, within the visible width?

Does somebody have a plugin or a macro anywhere? Or is there a specific settings option I am missing?

Comment: Well ... if anything -- this functionality is language-specific (must be implemented separately for each language). For PHP I have found 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18264 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-13469 3) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35039 4) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-27218 . As for JavaScript: 5) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11619 6) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7840 More generic (?) 7) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119270